# Resampling Live Websocket Ticks to Candles using Pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I am trying to resample live ticks from KiteTicker websocket into OHLC candles using pandas and this is the code I have written, which works fine with single instrument (The commented trd_portfolio on line 9) but doesn't work with multiple instruments (Line 8) as it mixes up data of different instruments.

Is there any way to relate the final candles df to instrument tokens? or make this work with multiple intruments?

I would like to run my algo on multiple instruments at once, please suggest if there is a better way around it.

```
from kiteconnect import KiteTicker;
from kiteconnect import KiteConnect;
import logging
import time,os,datetime,math;
import winsound
import pandas as pd

trd_portfolio = {954883:"USDINR19MARFUT",4632577:"JUBLFOOD"} 
# trd_portfolio = {954883:"USDINR19MARFUT"}

trd_tkn1 = [];

for x in trd_portfolio:
    trd_tkn1.append(x)


c_id = '****************'
ak = '************'
asecret = '*************************'

kite = KiteConnect(api_key=ak)
print('[*] Generate access Token : ',kite.login_url())
request_tkn = input('[*] Enter Your Request Token Here : ')[-32:];
data = kite.generate_session(request_tkn, api_secret=asecret)
kite.set_access_token(data['access_token'])
kws = KiteTicker(ak, data['access_token'])

#columns in data frame
df_cols = ["Timestamp", "Token", "LTP"]

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=[],columns=df_cols, index=[])

def on_ticks(ws, ticks):

    global data_frame, df_cols

    data = dict() 

    for company_data in ticks:
        token = company_data["instrument_token"]
        ltp = company_data["last_price"]
        timestamp = company_data['timestamp']

        data[timestamp] = [timestamp, token, ltp]

    tick_df = pd.DataFrame(data.values(), columns=df_cols, index=data.keys()) #
    data_frame = data_frame.append(tick_df)

    ggframe=data_frame.set_index(['Timestamp'],['Token'])
    print ggframe
    gticks=ggframe.ix[:,['LTP']]
    candles=gticks['LTP'].resample('1min').ohlc().dropna()
    print candles

def on_connect(kws , response):
    print('Connected')
    kws.subscribe(trd_tkn1)
    kws.set_mode(kws.MODE_FULL, trd_tkn1)

def on_close(ws, code, reason):
    print('Connection Error')


kws.on_ticks = on_ticks
kws.on_connect = on_connect
kws.on_close = on_close

kws.connect()
```

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to the Kite API, but I've been looking at some code snippets that use it trying to figure out another issue I'm having related to websockets. I came across this open question, and I think I can help, though I can't really test this solution.

The problem I think is that you're not calculating OHLC for each "token"... it just does it for all tokens.

```
data_frame = data_frame.append(tick_df)
ggframe=data_frame.set_index('Timestamp')
candles=ggframe.groupby('token').resample('1min').agg({'LTP':'ohlc'})
```

You'll get a multi-index output, but the column names might not quite line up for the rest of your code. To fix that:

```
candles.columns=['open','high','low','close']
```